# Customizable jQuery datetimepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins

I am finding a date time picker plugin which have feature scrolling left to right or right to left. It should be work on mobile screen also. I am sharing a picture what I want. I found a link which is so nearest from my query but in this plugin time picker is not showing.

***Plugin Url*** http://www.bestjquery.com/?jGUMy1Ky

Suggest any other plugin or customizable plugin.

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

@NoobProgrammerI totally do agree with you & for that, I have made some change in that plugin & modified it. Here is the code. **codepen.io/hardenrahul/pen/EoGmwd**

Answer (score 3):

A jQuery/Bootstrap 3 datetime picker plugin rich of features and highly customizable is **eonasdan bootstrap-datetimepicker**:

- http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

or its fork (and successor) **Tempus Dominus** available both for Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4:

- https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-3/
- https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/

A jQuery-only plugin with several options is:

- web site w/demos/docs: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/
- github repo: https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker

As suggest already by NoobProgrammer **DateBox** is a good mobile friendly option:

- web site w/demos/docs: http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/
- github repo: https://github.com/jtsage/jtsage-datebox

As completely mobile friendly alternative, but with separated date and time pickers is **pickadate.js**:

- web site w/demos/docs: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/
- github repo: https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js

---

As a guideline to select a JS plugin I suggest, besides to view offered functionalities, to check also:

- github repo for number of contributions, "freshness" of code (latest commit), number of forks
- number of posts here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Try this one : [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/)

It's Something like this

[image: Image References]